# Free ASP.Net (MVC/WebForms) based CMS which has plugins built in for connecting to Orkut and Facebook

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

I looking for free ASP.NET based content management system (CMS) which has the following features:

- Blogs (Admin, some super users can have their own blogs)
- Forums (Admins can create forums. Some moderation features)
- Admin Dashboard
- Integration with LinkedIn, Orkut and Facebook (native or through freely available add-ons)
- Support for moderated user registration (moderated by Admin)

[Windows Sharepoint services 3.0](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/fx100503841033.aspx) is an option. With some tweaking, it supports all the above and there are free third party web parts available.

> **NB:** The CMS listed must be free, as in beer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to go with Umbraco for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check the [free edition](http://www.kentico.com/Download/Free-edition.aspx) of Kentico CMS.

Comment: It doesn't offer anything above umbraco and the restrictions on the free version are not practical for a community website. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Sitefinity](http://www.sitefinity.com). It has the first three features built-in. I'm not sure what you mean by integration with social networks, but what Sitefinity has is bookmarking content from the CMS in those networks. Moderated user registration can be handled by the addition of a custom Membership provider, the same way as in ASP.NET